# Why "Program type already present: org.apache.commons.lang3.CharSetUtils"

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, azure-iot-hub

I've mashed a couple of projects together (one of which is azure iot), for Android build. I've spent a few days patching up errors, and am now stuck on this one:

> Program type already present: org.apache.commons.lang3.CharSetUtils
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.apache.commons.lang3.CharSetUtils, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

I have seen other posts about other libraries, but this did not help me. I check the dependencies, and all of the references to the lang3 library are the same version (and all used by Azure).

Any ideas what this is, how to fix it, or in general how to debug this?

Gradle build file. Note all builds well if I omit the last dependency on Azure at the bottom. But I do need Azure!

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':shimmerDriver')
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    implementation ('com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1')
    compile files('libs/AndroidBluetoothLibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/androidplot-core-0.5.0-release.jar')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Remote binary dependency
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.5.37'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might appear from caching so you can run

> ./gradlew clean cleanBuildCache :app:assembleDebug

from command line.

Can you post it here so I can help you ?.
You may check the `implementation` , `classpath`.

Hope this help you .

Comment: I have done a clean, no luck. I've started over, with the two programs both compile and run just fine, which I am combining. I get this clash when I add the dependency for azure. Here's my gradle file

Comment: I'm a novice at Java, what do you mean by 'check implementation, classpath' ?